# Issue while removing doc from SVN

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I am trying to remove doc from SVN repo by using ISVNClientAdapter .

i got the exception as "Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup' if it was interrupted  in subversion plugin  java". 
then I tried to clean up manually. But It was not working.

So I tried to run following command to delete WC DB pending processes,

sqlite3 .svn/wc.db "delete from work_queue"

and then again I tried to run:

ISVNClientAdapter.remove(filesToDelete, true);

But now it is giving exception as ,

"trying to get lock for already locked files"

Any suggestions, Why this issue is there?

Comment: I cant remove all data as my application is using that.

Comment: I have tried to fetch the Details from work_queue :
2154|(sync-file-flags {file name})   
what is the significance of this log ?